# Outlook macro works only for one account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I have been using outlook macro to move all drafts directly to outbox:

```
 Sub SendAllDrafts()
' Send the messages in the Drafts folder (ignore any subfolders)
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send ALL the items in your default Drafts folder?", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
Dim fldDraft As MAPIFolder, msg As Outlook.MailItem, intCount As Integer
Set fldDraft = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
intCount = 0
Do While fldDraft.Items.Count > 0
    Set msg = fldDraft.Items(1)
    msg.Send
    intCount = intCount + 1
Loop
If Not (msg Is Nothing) Then Set msg = Nothing
Set fldDraft = Nothing
MsgBox intCount & " messages sent", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Macro does work on one account but when i switch to a different account I get an error:
"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Outlook does not recognize one or more names." When I press debug it points a yellow arrow on "msg.Send" line. [image: PrintScreen]

Comment: it seems to be an issue with some messages in that folder, not with the macro. Have you tried sending them manually?

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I created some new messages and it worked out. Sorry for that noob question then :)

Comment: You may want to implement some error handling in your macro:)

Comment: How can i give you some reputation?